# Dimension of Solution Space from characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is $4\times4$ matrix with characteristic polynomial $x^4-x^3-6x^2+4x+8 $, then what would be the dimension of the solution space $ AX = 2X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial can be factored as
$$
x^4 - x^3 - 6x^2 + 4x + 8 = (x-2)^2(x+1)(x+2)
$$
We can therefore deduce that the dimension of the solution space to $Ax = 2x$ (that is, the eigenspace associated with $\lambda = 2$) is at least $1$ and at most $2$.

**Examples:**

$$
\pmatrix{2\\&2\\&&-1\\&&&-2}, \quad 
\pmatrix{2&1\\&2\\&&-1\\&&&-2}
$$

Comment: Some example where it is 1 and other example where it is 2?

Comment: Complete sentences?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I would try to post in complete sentences.

Comment: You're welcome.  Do those examples work for you?

Comment: Ya. What are the bases of  eigenspaces (corresponding to eigenvalue 2)  in these examples ?

Comment: That's for you to figure out